# SQL or procedure to conditionally insert or update in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, database-migration, sql-scripts

I don't have much of a hands-on in SQL and procedures. I need a migration script wherein I need to update or insert a table based on data in other two tables.

> **Organization:** 
> *id*   *name*  *pid* 
> *1*   *org1*  *null* 
> *2*
>     *org2*  *null* 
> *3*
>     *org3*  *1* 
> *4*
>     *org4*  *2*
>
> **Org_Channel:** 
> *org_id*   *channel* 
> *1*         *CH_100* 
> *2*
>           *CH_101*

**Organization** table has a parent-child self referenced relation. (pid **null** in case of parent). **Org_Channel** is a mapping table for ***parent*** organizations only.

Now I have a third table **Org_Settings** in which I need to migrate the data based on the above two tables. Each record here indicates a organization id, a setting name which is prefixed by channel name(for child org.this will be parent org.channel), and a flag. I need a migration SQL script / procedure for a setting **Sign_On** to be enabled as **'Y'** for *every organization*

 
The current table is something like this:

> **Org_Settings:** 
> *org_id*   *s_name*              *enabled* 
> *1*       *CH_100_Sign_On*    *N* 
> *1*       *CH_100_X_O*          *Y*
>   
> *4*       *CH_101_Sign_On*   *Y*

Now **Org_Settings** may or may not contain entry for each org. Also I need to migrate such that, if entry is present for Sign_On then need to update ***enabled = Y***. Such that the result would be:

> **Org_Settings:** 
> *org_id*   *s_name*              *enabled* 
> *1*       *CH_100_Sign_On*    *Y* 
> *2*       *CH_101_Sign_On*    *Y*
>   
> *3*       *CH_100_Sign_On*    *Y* 
> *4*       *CH_101_Sign_On*    *Y*

I could think of pseudo code like:

```
for i in each org
    var pid = getPid(i)
    var id = (null == pid) ? i : pid
    var channel = getChannel(id);
    var sname = channel + "_Sign_On"
    if(settingsEntryExists(i, sname))
        updateSettingsEnable(i, sname, 'Y')
    else
        insertSettings(i, sname, 'Y')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `MERGE INTO` statement. I did not understand the logic behind updating to 'Y' if entry exists and also inserting 'Y' if it does not exist. Isn't it same as simple insert?. or am I missing something? . You may tweak this query slightly if there is some missing info to clarify my question above.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/469d6/2)

```
MERGE 
INTO    Org_Settings d 
USING   ( select 
                org.id org_id, 
                ch.channel|| 
                '_Sign_On' s_name , 
                'Y'        enabled 
        FROM 
                Organization org
        JOIN    Org_Channel  ch ON NVL(org.pid,id) = ch.org_id
        )s 
ON ( d.org_id  = s.org_id 
                AND d.s_name = s.s_name )
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET d.enabled = 'Y' 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT
        (org_id,s_name,enabled 
        ) VALUES 
        (s.org_id,s.s_name,s.enabled 
        );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It solved my problem. I appreciate your time for also providing it in SQLFiddle..

Comment: And the reason for updating and not just inserting was because there are already records with same setting name for the org.with enabled value as ‘N’